# jquery append not working in IE/Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML and subsequent jQuery which appends the related HTML elements after the JSON request has been retrieved.

This implementation works in Google Chrome + Android browser + Safari, but is not populating the data in Firefox or Internet Explorer 9.

**** Works in Chrome, Android browser, Firefox 4 ... does not work in Firefox 3.x and IE.

Static HTML:

```
   <header class=line>
                       <div class="unit size3of4">
                            <h2 class="fullname"></h2>
                            <h4 class="nickname"></h4>
                       </div>
   </header>
```

The jQuery code:

```
<script>
function load_user_info() {
        var content_url = 'rest.api.url.com';
        $.getJSON(content_url, {id:'11xx1122xx11'}, function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                if (key == "fullname") {$('.fullname').append(value);}
                else if (key == "nickname") {$('.nickname').append(value);}
            });
         });
    }

 load_user_info();
 </script>
```

Slightly confused about the behavior between browsers.  I can guarantee the JSON request is returning two variables:  fullname & nickname and have confirmed this

In Firefox using the FireBug plugin I see the results of `console.log(data)`.
In Chrome I see the results of the `console.log(data)` and the successful display of the fullname & nickname in the HTML after the JSON request.

Using jQuery 1.6.1 if it helps ...

JSON Output:

```
 {"fullname":"johnny fartburger", "nickname":"jf"}
```

Comment: Do you have a sample of what is contained in the JSON response?

Comment: yes, i've updated the question with the JSON response

Comment: I created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nM8Nv/1/) out of this thing. Works for me in Firefox.

Comment: Johnny Fartburger lives in IE and Firefox.  Hmmm.  maybe I need to implement this with ` $(document).ready(function() {});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resulting problem was from the actual JSON data not being retrieved in IE.  Hours and hours of search turned up the problem was that `XDomainRequest` is not natively supported by jQuery, specifically in a `$.getJSON` request

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8283

In the end, I wrote a `try {} catch {}` statement that checks to see if `$.browser.msie` and if it is, do not use `$.getJSON` to retrieve the results, rather:

```
if ($.browser.msie) {
 var xdr = new XDomainRequest();
 xdr.open('GET', url);
 xdr.onload = function() {
     var data = $.parseJSON(this.responseText);
     show_data(data);                
 }
 xdr.send();
} else {
 $.getJSON(url, function(data){
     show_data(data);
 });
}
```

So ... **conclusion** append **does work** in IE (7/8/9) and Firefox (3/4) but not when the AJAX results aren't being returned.  Thanks everyone for your help and insight.

Answer (score 3):

I'm slightly perplexed by what you're doing.  I think the following code:

```
$.each(data, function (key, value) {
    if (key == "fullname") {
        $('.fullname').append(value);
    } else if (key == "nickname") {
        $('.nickname').append(value);
    }
});
```

could be more easily represented by this:

```
$('.fullname').append(data.fullname);
$('.nickname').append(data.nickname);
```

I don't know if this will solve your problem, but it would certainly be an improvement.

Comment: I tried this ... didn't fix the behavior in Firefox ;; however, thank you for the improvement tip for the code.  Optimize is part 2 after functional is fixed!

Answer (score 0):

`.append()` takes a HTML string as a parameter to append to the existing content. You probably want to replace the element's text, use `.text()` or `.html()` instead, depending on the contents of the `value` variable.

Comment: That's true, but it's hardly the problem here. A selector in Firefox would be a selector in Chrome too.

Comment: @lonesomeday: You're right, it seems I've got my own RTFM to do. I edited my answer as if nothing happened, now it's not wrong, just irrelevant. :)

Answer (score 0):

`.append(value)` is not very safe (for example if value="div").
You should use `.html(value)`

Answer (score 0):

And what does `data` contain? I think `.append` is used to append *elements*. If data is plain text, that might not work (haven't tried it actually). Chrome uses a different engine and may convert the text to a textnode in the DOM.

Use `.text()` or `.html()` to set the contents of an element.

Comment: Modifying the code and using your suggestion didn't make a difference?              $('.fullname').text(data.fullname);
            $('.nickname').text(data.nickname);

Answer (score 0):

as an alternative with `appendTo`, try to use `.text()` too

Comment: sometimes similar minor problems are automatically solved by refreshing browsers. if u see output on console, then except implemented styling, it must appear.

Comment: MLS .. your comment was the right hint.  the json output **wasn't** showing in the console for IE9 which is what got me onto the answer.  cheers